# JQuery: second function does not get called correctly on.change

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a Django APP that has a form with 3 fields: `department`, `province`, `district` (there are more, but the problem is with these 3).

So when user changes department selected option, a call to the backend should be made to retrieve a province and a district.

The same should happen when user, changes province, a call to the backend must be done to retrieve the correspondent districts.

To achieve this I've 2 functions, that do the job correctly: `get_provinces()`, `get_districts()`.

**My problem:** how to make sure that the second function, that is `get_districts()`, gets called on changing department?

Code:

```js
function get_provinces() {
  var val_d = $("#id_shipping_department").val()
  $.ajax({
    url: "/province/",
    data: { // Pass parameters in separate object
      d_name: val_d
    },
  }).done(function(result) {
    $("#id_shipping_province").html(result);
  });
}


function get_districts() {
  var val_d = $("#id_shipping_department").val()
  var val_p = $("#id_shipping_province").val()
  $.ajax({
    url: "/district/",
    data: { // Pass parameters in separate object
      d_name: val_d,
      p_name: val_p
    },
  }).done(function(result) {
    $("#id_shipping_district").html(result);
  });
}

$("document").ready(function() {


  $("#id_shipping_department").change(function() {
    get_provinces();
    get_districts();

  });


  $("#id_shipping_province").change(function() {
    get_districts();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_cellphone">Celular o  teléfono:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="cellphone" maxlength="15" required id="id_cellphone">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_shipping_address1">Dirección de envío:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="shipping_address1" maxlength="100" required id="id_shipping_address1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_shipping_address2">Dirección de envío 2 (opcional):</label></th>
    <td>

      <input type="text" name="shipping_address2" maxlength="100" id="id_shipping_address2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_shipping_department">Shipping department:</label></th>
    <td>

      <select name="shipping_department" id="id_shipping_department">
        <option value="Tumbes">Tumbes</option>

        <option value="Pasco">Pasco</option>

        <option value="Ucayali">Ucayali</option>

        <option value="Callao">Callao</option>

        <option value="Ayacucho">Ayacucho</option>


        <option value="Áncash">Áncash</option>

        <option value="Loreto">Loreto</option>

        <option value="Cajamarca">Cajamarca</option>

        <option value="Lambayeque">Lambayeque</option>

        <option value="Moquegua">Moquegua</option>

        <option value="Puno">Puno</option>

        <option value="Tacna">Tacna</option>

        <option value="Arequipa">Arequipa</option>

        <option value="Apurímac">Apurímac</option>

        <option value="Junín">Junín</option>

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_shipping_province">Shipping province:</label></th>
    <td>

      <select name="shipping_province" id="id_shipping_province">
        <option value="Contralmirante Villar">Contralmirante Villar</option>

        <option value="Tumbes">Tumbes</option>

        <option value="Zarumilla">Zarumilla</option>

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_shipping_district">Shipping district:</label></th>
    <td>

      <select name="shipping_district" id="id_shipping_district">
        <option value="Canoas de Punta Sal">Canoas de Punta Sal</option>

        <option value="Zorritos">Zorritos</option>

        <option value="Casitas">Casitas</option>

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: @zer00ne it does not, if I change department only province gets changed. I was hoping that on deparment change province and district should change. Pero solo province changes on department change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be due to the asynchronous nature of js.
 You can try using `async` `await`

I have changed the js code, you can try this:

```
function get_provinces() {
    // notice the promise
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var val_d = $("#id_shipping_department").val()
        $.ajax({
            url: "/province/",
            data: { // Pass parameters in separate object
                d_name: val_d
            },
        }).done(function (result) {
            $("#id_shipping_province").html(result);
            resolve(result)
        });
    });
}


function get_districts() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var val_d = $("#id_shipping_department").val()
        var val_p = $("#id_shipping_province").val()
        $.ajax({
            url: "/district/",
            data: { // Pass parameters in separate object
                d_name: val_d,
                p_name: val_p
            },
        }).done(function (result) {
            $("#id_shipping_district").html(result);
            resolve(result)
        });
    });
}

$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#id_shipping_department").change(async /* <--- */ function () {
        await /* <--- */ get_provinces();
        await /* <--- */ get_districts();

    });

    $("#id_shipping_province").change(async /* <--- */ function () {
        await get_districts();
    });

});
```